# IE8 jquery .bing firing immediately

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, click, bind

I have a function that fires on click (to set some stuff and do an ajax call). I also bind and undo function onto the control that fired it. (It ticks a box on and off). So clicking the control changes the class to show it ticked and binds the click event to an untick function.

The problem is in IE8 (other browsers are fine), It seems to fire the RemoveDataType function as soon as I have bound it to the click event. It's as if it clicked itself.  Can anyone tell me why this would happen and is there a work around out there>?

Really appreciate any input on this. Thansk

Code:

```
 $("#classifydropdown_content_item_" + id).toggleClass("classifydropdown_content_item_checked classifydropdown_content_item_unchecked");
$("#classifydropdown_content_item_" + id).bind('click', function () {
    RemoveDataType(id);
});
```

Comment: try to replicate your issue in a jsfiddle. Binding an event doesn't fire it, even in IE8. And instead of guessing that it could be, you could simply test if effictively event is fired or not

Comment: I can run it in debug and if I click the control id=classifydropdown_content_item_1, it toggles the class then binds and runs straight to the function RemoveDataType(id);